# Calling another site?

Tags: php, apache

OK - Simply, I'm building a site that needs to incorporate an existing page, protected with a simple .htaccess/.htpasswd script.

How can I pass the username/password to the receiving site using PHP?

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

UPDATE - I think I may have over-complicated the question. What I'm needing to do is essentially:

```
<a href="http://username:password@url.com/" target="_blank">The link<a>
```

Which, actually, works perfectly in everything but IE . I'm golden if I can find a more universal, simple solution.

Thanks in advance for your help, all!

Comment: Can you define how you want to "incorporate" the existing page?  Is it in an iframe?  Are you simply linking to it?

Comment: meagar - I can go either way. The object here is simply to embed an external, web-based hardware control application/demo into a standard site. The existing control app has its own graphics/navigation. Ideally, if the user logs out of the control app, I'd like them returned to the main site.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with alxp that you should get to know cURL. The basic gist is that when using HTTP Basic Auth, credentials are sent as a base64 encoded string in the headers. Here's a simple example using PHP's cURL extension:

```
$url = '...';
$username = '...';
$password = '...';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username . ":" . $password)
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print $result;
```

Hope that helps! Read up on [HTTP Basic here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) and [PHP's cURL extension here](http://php.net/curl)

Please keep in mind that this is example code and contains no error checking, etc.

Comment: This works nicely, Paul, but creates two problems... First, the resulting page is lacking its graphics and Nav (it seems to think it's a part of the calling site)... I'm reading-up on the cURL extension now, but if you have any quick ideas, I'd appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `file_get_contents` function to download the page, you can use something like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://username:password@example.com/path/');
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll be best off if you get to know the curl library, a good introduction can be found [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/15/10/2), including how to submit a suername and password.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the username and password in plain-text via a simple http redirect, in the format

```
http://username:password@yoursite.com/yourpage
```

However, you probably shouldn't - some browsers now explicitly bother you for confirmation when they see this syntax.

You can hide this from the user however, by loading the above URL with file_get_contents() and dumping the results to the browser.  This won't work if the HTML output of the page uses relative links to external files (images/js/css) on its server.

Comment: IIRC MSIE strips it out. But this syntax still works via Curl if you can be bothered proxying all the access and dealing with hard-coded URLs in the remote site